# error 1004 Insert method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro and I want to copy the row above the active cell row and use that as my template row (because it has formulas in that row). I then want to insert that row above the active cell row. When I run my code below, I get the Error 1004 Insert method of Range Class Failed. When I select debug, the following line is highlighted.

ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=TempRow

I do not have any merged cells in the table, except at the top in the header, and the user will not be entering any rows there. The sheet is not currently protected, but will be once I can get this code figured out. I will then add code to unprotect and protect the sheet before and after the macro runs. Ido not know what to do to resolve this issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Sub ADD_ROW_1 ()
Dim TempRow As Range

Set TempRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Row).EntireRow
TempRow.Copy

ActiveSheet.Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=TempRow

'    Clear cells code here
Range("A" & TempRow.Row + 1).ClearContents
Range("B" & TempRow.Row + 1).ClearContents
Range("E" & TempRow.Row + 1).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: The code works for me, although could be changed slightly. If you made a new workbook and tested this code in it does it work?

Comment: I have pasted a few rows into a new wb and copied and pasted the macro into that wb vba module and got the same result when I ran the macro. There is one cell that does a vlookup to another worksheet (WS B) in this wb. There were a couple of cells that were merged in the lookup table, but I have removed them and still got the same results. Column A contains a dropdown, which uses column B in WS B as the source data for the dropdown.

Still confused and do not have a functional macro. What should I change slightly to make this work better.

Comment: Firstly just try in a fresh worksheet/workbook without your data (just put some random numbers or something in a row to test) and make sure it works first. Then maybe you have to go through your cells in the row testing each time until it stops working (or starts in your case). 

You could also try specifying the sheet rather than `ActiveSheet` or just do `ActiveCell.Offset(-1).EntireRow` or try using `Selection` instead of `ActiveCell`. Maybe someone else can see something wrong that I can't but for me that's what you will have to do.

Comment: I have updated the code as listed below in a new spreadsheet with none of the data linked over. It is all just simple data, Same results. I am running office 365, so it is the latest iteration, so I don't know if that would impact anything. This code is so simple, I wouldn't think this would be the problem.
`code`
Sub ROW_INSERT_1()

Dim TempRow As Range

Set TempRow = Selection.Offset(-1).EntireRow
TempRow.Copy

Rows(Selection.Row).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=TempRow

End Sub
`code`

Comment: Try without the CopyOrigin.

Comment: That works. Thanks so very much for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't notice it at first because it worked for me but you didn't use the CopyOrigin correctly. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) about the correct usage of the `Insert` function.